# Access localhost from another computer on the same network (flask python server)?

Tags: python, flask, networking, localhost

my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
    print('ok')
    return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

**Firewall settings**
Created 2 inbound rules for TCP and UDP on PORT 5000

**> ipconfig /all**

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%6
                                    192.168.1.1
```

Still I can't access 192.168.1.2:5000 from another computer on the same network. (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Is there something else I can try ? (or somehow debug to check what is blocking the connection ?)

Comment: Could you possibly need to add outbound rules? It doesn't seem like you would need to, but maybe there's something blocking it that way?

Comment: @manny Still nothing :(

Comment: Hm. Try having it listen specifically on 192.168.1.2.

Comment: So, first of all, make sure that you can ping each other. Then run flask with the host set to '0.0.0.0' through --host= or through app.run(host). Check if your app is listenning with netstat -nlp or equivalent depending on your OS. Connection Timeout is propably a network problem, not a flask problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the firewall , I it works with me only if it stopped .